# How to connect a Node.js project hosted on AWS with Cloudflare without using Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, hosting, cloudflare

How can I connect my Node.js project hosted on AWS with Cloudflare without using Route 53? I initially used Route 53 to connect the DNS with my instance, but I recently learned that it is possible to connect the instance using only the DNS service or Cloudflare. Can someone provide guidance on how to connect my AWS instance with Cloudflare?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect my AWS instance with Cloudflare"?

Comment: Create a DNS record in Cloudflare that points to your server. Just like you did in Route53.